# ¿Cómo puedo quitar la propiedad required de un campo de texto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Quisiera que la propiedad `required` sea quitada o removida de este campo de texto, este debe de ocurrir cuando selecciono alguna opción de un `select`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#listaOpciones').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $('#listaOpciones option:selected');
    if (selectedOption.val() == 2 || selectedOption.val() == 4) {
      $("#tel").removeClass("required");
    } else {}
  });
});
```

Comment: O cual es el metodo para borrar atributos de una etiqueta html, esto me podria ayudar

Comment: el atributo es el que use en la respuesta removeAttr()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí un pequeño ejemplo, espero te sea de utilidad:

```
<input type="text" id="myTest" required value="" />
    <button onclick="poner();">
        poner
    </button>
    <button onclick="quitar();">
        quitar
    </button>
    <script>
        function poner() {
            $('#myTest').prop("required", true);
        }
        function quitar() {
            $('#myTest').removeAttr("required");
        }
    </script>
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias fredyfx por su colaboracion

Comment: de nada, seguimos colaborando al aprendizaje colectivo!

Answer (score 3):

En lugar de usar `removeClass` que elimina una de las clases declaradas en el atributo `class`, debes usar [`removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) que elimina el atributo completo del elemento.

Antes.. `<input type="text" required>` y después .. `<input type="text">`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#listaOpciones').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $('#listaOpciones').val();
    if (selectedOption == 2 || selectedOption == 4) {
      // aquí haces el cambio.
      $("#tel").removeAttr("required");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias rnd por su colaboracion me ha sido de mucha ayuda lo estare implementando

Comment: @JuanDavid De nada! A propósito, si esta u otra respuesta te sirvió, no te olvides de [aceptarla](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/227)

Comment: @JuanDavid solo puedes aceptar una :(

Answer (score 0):

Podria implementar algo como ser

```js
$(function(){
  
   $("#opciones").change(function(){
     
        var selecion = $(this).val();
         
        if(selecion == "3"){
             $("#textbox1").removeAttr("required");
          }
     
     });
  
     $("#validar").click(function(){
       
          alert($("#contenido").html());
       
       });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opciones">
  <option value ="1" >opcin 1</option>
  <option value ="2" >opcin 2</option>
  <option value ="3" >opcin 3</option>
</select>

    <div id="contenido">
       <input type="text" id="textbox1" required />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="validar" id="validar" />
```

En el ejemplo veras que al seleccionar la opcion 3 se quita el `required`
con el boton podras ver el html que renderiza el textbox, presionalo antes y despues de seleccionar la opcion del combo

Si usa la developer tool del browser podrias inspaccionar el html que se genera

**>>si quiero que el value="" tenga un valor diferente cual seria la linea de codigo correspondiente**

Imagino te refieres al value del textbox, en ese caso solo usarias

```
$("#textbox1").val("valor");
```

Comment: Gracias Leandro que buen ejemplo es lo que necesitaba, bendiciones, Leandro una ultima pregunta y si quiero que el value="" tenga un valor diferente cual seria la linea de codigo correspondiente

Comment: @JuanDavid respondi sobre la pregunta

Comment: Gracias Leandro, muchas gracias

Comment: @JuanDavid te hace falta aceptar la respuesta